# Angular 2: empty array in component HTML

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am doing a simple project:

There are 2 input sliders and a button 'Calculate', when the button is pressed, calculations are done and printed to a table.

I'm having a little problem, when I press the button, the table Component does show the answer array is empty, but if I print it out from the constructor to the console, everything is shown.

Could someone help? 
I want to do a `*ngFor` and loop through the elements later.

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  loanArray: Payment[] = [];

  setCalculatedPayments(loanSum: number, loanTime:number) {
    this.loanArray = new PaymentsCalculated(loanSum, loanTime).calculateLoanDetails();
  }

  getCalculatedPayments() {
    return this.loanArray;
  }
}
```

Loan Component:

```
export class LoanTablesComponent implements OnInit {

  loanArray: Payment[] = []; // is it always empty?

  constructor(private DataService: DataService) {
    this.loanArray = this.DataService.getCalculatedPayments();
    // here it prints the loanArray as required
    // but if I print out in the .html, it is always zero
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Calculation Component:

```
export class CalculatorComponent implements OnInit {

  loanSum: number;
  loanTime: number;

  constructor(private DataService: DataService) {
    setTimeout(() => this.loanSum = 500);
    setTimeout(() => this.loanTime = 1);
    // for input sliders
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  calculatePayments(): void{
    this.DataService.setCalculatedPayments(this.loanSum, this.loanTime);
  }

}
```

Thank You for help, just learning and seeking advice(:

Comment: What's the relationship between `CalculatorComponent` and `LoanTablesComponent`?

Comment: Calculator shows the UI of the inputs to input for calculations, when button is pressed it gives data to the Data Service, the LoanTables outputs the tables,taking the data from the Data service

Comment: Alright. But I meant how are they related **in the component tree**? (e.g. Is one the child of the other?) Looks like you have a timing issue: you try to read the data as soon as `LoanTablesComponent` instantiates but it isn't set until you call `setCalculatedPayments()`. If `loanArray` contains a non-primitive value, I don't think change-detection can work with your setup. Maybe try replacing `loanArray` in `LoanTablesComponent` by a [get property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)?

Comment: But shouldn't it still calculate, even though the inputs are set in the constructor of Calculator?

Comment: I don't think the problem is that it doesn't calculate. The problem is that the result of the calculation isn't passed through.